`zero_grad` before `step` cause gradient explosion?
I have this simplified code snippet, which loads an image and feed to a model of 1 CNN layer.
def main(cfg):
model = Model().cuda()
dataset = Dataset(cfg)
optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=cfg.learning_rate)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    dataset, 
    batch_size=cfg.batch_size, 
    num_workers=cfg.num_workers,
    shuffle=False,
    pin_memory=True    
)

p = next(model.parameters())
for epoch in range(cfg.max_epochs):

    for idx, (target) in enumerate(train_dataloader, start=1):
        to_pil_image(target.squeeze(0)).save('test.jpg')

        print(p[0, 0, 0, 0])

        target = target.to('cuda')
        target = F.interpolate(target, (256, 256), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
        output = model(target)
        loss = F.mse_loss(target, output)
        loss.backward()
        # torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=0)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        optimizer.step()

I noticed that when calling optimizer.step() then optimizer.zero_grad(), the code works properly (loss decreases and the model converge).
But when I call zero_grad() then step(), then p.grad will be 0 after zero_grad() (which is expected), but p[0, 0, 0, 0] will become nan after step().
Is this an expected behaviour? Since to my understanding, calling zero_grad() before step() should have the effect of not updating the weights at all.

What does p refer to here?

@Ivan it is a parameter of the model, I use it to point out that calling optimizer.step() when p.grad = 0 causes p to become NaN

Try to wrap your parameters with torch.optim.AdamW(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()). The sample script works expected behavior to me. I guess your model would be problem on backward hooking.
